# Practical Threshold Signatures

Tags: rsa, threshold-cryptography

In [Practical Threshold Signature](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070209-new.pdf) it says that there is a requirement in which the RSA public exponent $e$ must be more than $l$. $l$ in this case is the number of players in the threshold group.

My question is: Why is there a constraint that the public exponent must be larger  than the number of players?

In my case, my public exponent must be 3 (due to limitation on another component), hence the number of player can only be 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with this paper, but there is (at least) the following reason. They define $\Delta = l!$, then require (right after equation 6) that $1 = \mathsf{gcd}(e', e) = \mathsf{gcd}(4\Delta^2, e) = \mathsf{gcd}(4(l!)^2, e)$.
This is not possible if $e \leq l$ (as then the GCD is $e\neq 1$).